# Split address column in streetname and number using SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with an address column.
Now I need to SELECT the streetname and number separately.

```
Address

Wallstreet 20
New Yorkavenue 30
New London Street 40
```

Needs to be:

```
Street:                Number:

Wallstreet             20
New Yorkavenue         30
New London Street      40
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does this have to do with regex?

Comment: It can be done with regex but in MariaDB 10, not in MySQL.

Comment: I removed the regex tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume that the number is the final "word" and separated by a space:

```
select replace(address, substring_index(address, ' ', -1), '') as street,
       substring_index(address, ' ', -1) as number
```

I happen to think that those two assumptions are very big assumptions, meaning that this might not work on all your rows.

Comment: but what if the street name contains a number? it could happen sometimes ;) but yes, a "perfect" solution doesn't exist so the replace function is still a good idea

Answer (score 2):

For Mysql probably you could create a [MYSQL SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) to separate the fields if the numbers are only in the address number and the address has no numbers.

Example

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(address, SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, ' ', -1), '') as  ADDRESS,   
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, ' ', -1) as NUMBER
FROM
    ADDRESSES
```

it's not a really good method in performance and probably clould be done with other ways but if the schema is allways like the example it could works

Also probably is better in performance to do it on client side in the language that fetch the data.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some string functions, like SUBSTRING_INDEX and LEFT.

Getting the Number is easy:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(Street, ' ', -1)
```

(yes, it's not actually a number, but I suppose it's the last part of the string after the last space, it can also be a string as 20/C).

Getting the street name is a little more tricky:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(Street,
    CHAR_LENGTH(Street)
    -CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Street, ' ', -1))
    -1
  ) AS street_name,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(Street, ' ', -1) AS street_number
FROM
  tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm may be some what late, but issues are still the same nower days :-)

The question was, how to split/select a streetname (Straßenname) and the number (Hausnummer) out of a adress string?

Therefor I created a function, to implement German DIN 5008:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008;
delimiter //

CREATE DEFINER=`vlw`@`%` FUNCTION `HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008`(
   oldStreet VARCHAR(255), formating BOOL
) RETURNS varchar(16) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
SET @oldString := oldStreet;
SET @newString := "";

tokenLoop: LOOP
END LOOP tokenLoop;
  -- are there no figures at the beginning of street name?
  IF NOT @oldString REGEXP '^[1-9]' THEN
    -- must be a word, to jump over
    SET @splitPoint := LOCATE(" ", @oldString);
    SET @oldString := SUBSTRING(@oldString, @splitPoint+1);
  ELSE
    -- Okay, we found the first figure
    -- Are there any chars inside the string including "."
    IF @oldString REGEXP '[a-z,A-Z,.,--,/," "]' THEN
      -- Are there any char directly behind a figure
      IF @oldString REGEXP '[0-9][a-z,A-Z,.,--,/," "]' THEN
        -- now we have to check step by step
        SET @i := 1;
        tokenPos: LOOP
          -- jump over the first figures
          IF NOT SUBSTRING(@oldString, @i, 1) REGEXP '[0-9]' THEN
            -- this is the first non figure
            IF formating THEN
              IF SUBSTRING(@oldString, @i, 1) REGEXP '[a-z,A-Z]' THEN
                -- If a char is directly written after figures, then add a blank between
                SET @oldString := CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@oldString,1,@i-1)," ",SUBSTRING(@oldString,@i));
                LEAVE tokenPos;
              ELSE
                IF SUBSTRING(@oldString, @i, 1) = "." THEN
                  -- this must be part of the street name, so we will loop some what
                  LEAVE tokenPos;
                END IF;
                -- SET @newString := concat(">xx>",REPLACE(@oldString," ",""));
                SET @newString := REPLACE(@oldString," ","");
                LEAVE tokenLoop;
              END IF;
              LEAVE tokenPos;
            ELSE
              IF SUBSTRING(@oldString, @i, 1) = "." THEN
                -- this must be part of the street name, so we will loop some what
                LEAVE tokenPos;
              ELSE
                -- the street number is found
                SET @newString := @oldString;
                LEAVE tokenLoop;
              END IF;
            END IF;
          END IF;
          SET @i := @i+1;
        END LOOP tokenPos;
      END IF;
      SET @splitPoint := LOCATE(" ", @oldString);
      IF SUBSTRING(@oldString, @splitPoint+1) REGEXP '[1-9]' THEN
        -- we have to split one more word
        SET @oldString := SUBSTRING(@oldString, @splitPoint+1);
      ELSE
        SET @newString := @oldString;
        LEAVE tokenLoop;
      END IF;
    ELSE
      IF formating AND @oldString REGEXP '[//][1-9]' THEN
        SET @i := LOCATE(@oldString,"//")+4;
        SET @oldString := CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@oldString,1,@i)," ",SUBSTRING(@oldString,@i+1));
       ELSEIF formating THEN
        SET @oldString := REPLACE(@oldString," ","");
      END IF;
      SET @newString := @oldString;
      LEAVE tokenLoop;
    END IF;
  END IF;
RETURN @newString;
END //

delimiter ;
```

There is an additional BOOLEAN parameter, to reformat the number part of the address against DIN 5008. But the reformating part isn't finaly done yet.
Now we can test it with some examples:

```
select  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Mörikestr. 28/3",TRUE);
select  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Nettelbeckstraße 6 a",TRUE);
select  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Auf dem Brande 19a",TRUE);  ==>> "19 a"
select  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Auf dem Brande 19a",FALSE); ==>> "19a"
select  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Anger 1-3",TRUE);
select  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Straße des 17. Juni 12-16",TRUE);
select  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("L11 2",TRUE); -- z.B in Mannheim
select  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("111. 2",TRUE);
select  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Züricher Straße 17// 28",,TRUE);

-- Some special formating tests
SELECT  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Mörikestr. 28 / 3",TRUE);
SELECT  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("8 - 6",TRUE);
SELECT  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Straße des 17. Juni 12 - 16",TRUE);
SELECT  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Straße des 17. Juni 12- 16",TRUE);
SELECT  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("Straße des 17. Juni 12 -16",FALSE);

-- Next one is not DIN 5008, but was a loop issue inside function
SELECT  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("8 /App.6",FALSE);
SELECT  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("8 /App.6",TRUE);
SELECT  HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008("8/App.6",TRUE);
```

If you need only the street name, you have to use HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008() with formating FALSE, otherwise you can't find the numberpart within your adress.

```
SET @address := "Auf dem Brande 19a";
SELECT SUBSTRING(@address, 1, LOCATE(HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008(@address, FALSE),@address)-1);

SET @address := "Straße des 17. Juni 12-16";
SELECT SUBSTRING(@address, 1, LOCATE(HAUSNUMMER_DIN_5008(@address, FALSE),@address)-1);
```

That are my 5 cent
 Christian Eickhoff

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END LOOP tokenLoop;

IF NOT @oldString REGEXP '^[1-9]' THEN

```
SET @sp' at line 9
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone coming from Google: As you can't trust humans, I chose this way:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '[a-z"äöüß"\-\. ]+') AS street ,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '[0-9]+.*') AS number,
FROM
    ADDRESSES
```

Because this will also work on:

```
Streetname 5
Streetname 5B
Streetname 5 B
Streetn.5B
Street-Name5
Streetname 5 (+trailing Space)
Street name5
```

Comment: This is for mysql >8.0 only